# How can I remove the text but not the child elements?

Tags: jquery

can I remove with jQuery only the text in a  node but not the children elements ?

thanks

Comment: See also:[How do I select text nodes with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298750/how-do-i-select-text-nodes-with-jquery)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's my idea:

```
function removeText(element){
  var newElement = $('<' + element[0].nodeName + '/>');
  for(i=0; i < item.attributes.length; i++) {
    newElement.attr(item.attributes[i].name, item.attributes[i].value);
  } 
  element.children().each(function(){
    newElement.append(this);
  });
  element.replaceWith(newElement);
}
```

Comment: function stripText(element) {
  var item = element[0];
  var newElement = $('<' + item.nodeName + '/>');

  for (i=0; i<item.attributes.length; i++) {
   newElement.attr(item.attributes[i].name, item.attributes[i].value);
  }

  element.children().each(function(){
   newElement.append(this);
  });

  element.replaceWith(newElement);
  return newElement;
}

Comment: +1 Mandrake's solution resolves the issue of the element's attributes being removed.

Answer (score 64):

Best and easy solution to remove all text elements from certain div is

```
$("#firstDiv").contents().filter(function(){
    return (this.nodeType == 3);
}).remove();
```

Comment: Nitin, bro could you explain it a little please?

Comment: If you need to replace the text, replace `remove()` with `replaceWith("new text")`

Comment: Nice - Worked for me too

Comment: I have found the solution here even I was searching for a bit different thing - this idea is also good to keep only the element text removing all the inner html tags:
$(node).find('.export:first-child').contents().filter(function(){
                      return (this.nodeType == 3);
                  }).text().trim()

Answer (score 9):

This works for me:

```
$(elem).html($(elem).html().replace($(elem).text(),''));
```

This set the html content without the text content, it means that any html tag inside of elem will be keep without changes.

before:

```
<div>Hello<input type="text" name="username" value="world!"/></div>
```

after:

```
<div><input type="text" name="username" value="world!"/></div>
```

bye

Comment: Please add some explanation.

Comment: There are a few problems with this: 1) editing HTML with string functions like replace can break the markup (eg. if the text is ' ' or '"'), 2) anything matching the text is replaced (eg. if the text is 'user' then the name attribute will change), 3) If the text is spread out between children it won't work (eg. "<div>Hello<br />World</div>")

Answer (score -1):

It's easier for me to set a class for them all, in HTML and use empty() method in jQuery.

Comment: OP was asking about text nodes. You can't add classes to text nodes

Answer (score -6):

you cannot do that.Unless it is wrapped by an element.

Answer (score -12):

```
$('#someElement').text('');
```

Comment: are u sure ? it removes also the children. Maybe because I use jquery 1.2.3

Comment: this removes all the children in 1.4.2 as well

Comment: Rudism is correct. It removes everything within the element including the children.