# Clear text of div , but keep child nodes using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery: how to remove the text but not the children elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715167/jquery-how-to-remove-the-text-but-not-the-children-elements)

```
<div id="parent" style="border:2px solid red; width:300px;height:200px">
    text of parent
    <div id="child1" style="border:1px solid green; width:200px;height:80px"></div>
    <div id="child2" style="border:1px solid blue; width:200px;height:80px"></div>
</div>
```

In the above example, I want to clear only text `"text of parent"` of parent `div` (`parent`), keeping child nodes(`child 1`, `child2`) intact. How can I do this using jQuery?

Comment: Dup?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715167/jquery-how-to-remove-the-text-but-not-the-children-elements

Comment: Yup.. Duplicated.. Sorry, I dint find them before asking question :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
$("#parent").contents().filter(function(){
    return (this.nodeType == 3);
}).remove();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eUW47/1

Comment: I'd just use `.filter()`: http://jsfiddle.net/yBkG8/2/

Comment: You just taught me something new. Never heard of nodeType. That's brilliant.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use jQuery:

```
var div = document.getElementById("parent");
div.firstChild.data = "";​
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/Q8Bzv/

Comment: You're right, it's fixed now. :)

Comment: Yup.. good way to do it with plain javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var $children = $("#parent").children();
$("#parent").html("").append($children);​
```

Answer (score 0):

A general "remove all child text nodes" function (sorry, no jQuery):

```
function removeTextNodes(el) {
  var nodes = el.childNodes, i = nodes.length;
  while (i--)
    if (nodes[i].nodeType == 3) el.removeChild(nodes[i]);
}
```