# Remove html elements from the dom

Tags: jquery, dom, dom-manipulation

I'm trying to figure out how to remove the dash and colon here using jQuery. Is there a way? So far, I've tried `.empty` and `.remove` but I couldn't get it to work, unfortunately.

```
<p class="meta">
     <strong>Author Name</strong>
     –                                <-- remove this
     <time>June 7, 2013</time>
     :                                <-- remove this
</p>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: how to remove the text but not the children elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715167/jquery-how-to-remove-the-text-but-not-the-children-elements)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use...

```
$('.meta').contents().filter(function() { return this.nodeType == 3 }).remove()
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/97WDM/).

Comment: This is the correct answer. Only after posting my own answer, I saw yours.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$(function(){
   var $children = $('.meta').children();
   $('.meta').empty().append($children);
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QA2Ec/5/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(function(){
   $('p.meta').html($('p.meta').find('*'));
});
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/8Kezf/)**

Or try,

```
$(function(){
    $('p.meta').html(function(){ return $(this).find('*');});
});
```

**[Alternative](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/8Kezf/1/)**

**Updated,** if there are events attached with your child element then use [contents](http://api.jquery.com/contents) and [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter) like,

```
$(function(){
    $("p.meta").contents().filter(function(){ return this.nodeType == 3; }).remove();
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/8Kezf/3/)**

Refer [How can I change an element's text without changing its child elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106809/in-jquery-how-can-i-change-an-elements-text-without-changing-its-child-elements)

Comment: Problem if there are event listeners on those elements directly.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to re-create your $(".meta") DOM node, so you got to extract **strong** and **time**, empty your $(".meta") and insert previously stored nodes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [contents()](http://api.jquery.com/contents/), that returns all children (including text nodes). Then use [remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) to remove those text nodes.

http://jsfiddle.net/Pv3qX/

```
$(".meta").contents().filter(function() {
     return this.nodeType == 3; // 3 for TEXT_NODE
}).remove()
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/E6GYs/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).click(function(){
     $('.meta time').remove();
  })
    })
```