# convert <a> text string to dom element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I convert the text in a link to an html element?

I'm targetting the text with  `$('a').text();`    which returns the value but I can't add the element to it.

I've tried this:

```
var someText = $('a').text();
var theElement = $('< p >' + someText + '< /p >');
someText.replaceWith(theElement);
```

---

I know this supposedly would add a text element inside the link which is not the best practice but not even this works.

what I really need is to remove the whole text and rewrite it immediately after de link as a text element.

any help is appreciated. thank you

markup:

```
<li>
<a href="/"> <img src="image.png"> text to be converted to element </a>
</li>
```

what I want:

```
<li>
<a href="/"> <img src="image.png"></a>
<p> text to be converted to element </p>
</li>
```

Comment: Are you trying to select all of the links with jQuery?

Comment: no. I know how to properly target each element. thanks

Comment: Will you target them by `id` or `class`?

Comment: Not clear what you're after, maybe you can clarify it with an example

Comment: You're trying to replace an `<a>` element with a `<p>` element, containing the same text?

Comment: You are trying to replace a string with an element. Also, the replaceWith method actually receives a string. Third issue is that you cannot put spaces in your html element < p > doesn't work. Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ax24wj1w/

Comment: im targetting all a:first-child elements inside .grid li; i'll add the class later when the p element  exists!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
// iterate over each of the <a> elements within <li> elements:
$('li a').each(function() {
  // create a <p> element, setting its text
  // to that of the 'this' element (the <a>):
  $('<p>', {
    'text': this.textContent
  // insert that created <p> after the current <a> element:
  }).insertAfter(this);

  // filtering the childNodes of the current <a>:
  $(this).contents().filter(function() {
    // keeping only those that are of nodeType === 3
    // and therefore are textNodes:
    return this.nodeType === 3;
  // removing those nodes:
  }).remove();
});
```

```js
$('li a').each(function() {
  $('<p>', {
    'text': this.textContent
  }).insertAfter(this);
  $(this).contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3;
  }).remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="/">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/people" />text to be converted to element</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`Node.nodeType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType).
  - [`Node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent).
- jQuery:

  - [`contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/).
  - [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
  - [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
  - [`wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/).

Comment: It doesn't need to be voted up (unless others wish to do so); if it solved your problem - and was of more help than other answers - you're free to accept this (or any other) answer to reflect that.

Comment: I'm glad to have been of help, but if you feel this - or any other - answer has answered your question, your acceptance (checking the tick character (`✓`) beside the appropriate answer) would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Since `someText` is a string, not a jQuery element, you can't call `.replaceWith()` on it. Try something like this:

```
var someLink = $('a');
var someText = someLink.text();
var theElement = $('<p>' + someText + '</p>'); // no spaces inside tags
someLink.replaceWith(theElement);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0xxrL6zy/

---

**UPDATE** Since you added new information to your question, here's a solution to meet your needs:

```
var someLink = $('a');
var someText = someLink.text();
var someImg = someLink.find('img');
var theElement = $('<p>' + someText + '</p>');
someLink.html(someImg).after(theElement);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/mzbtr0qp/1/

Comment: im not trying to convert a link into text!

Comment: Then you should have been more clear when you originally posted your question. It's not cool to completely change the parameters of a question after people have already answered it. Regardless, I've updated my answer to reflect your new code.

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/cvgbqb8b/2/

```
var anchor = $('li a');
anchor.after('<p>' + anchor.text() + '</p>')
    .contents()
    .filter(function(){
        return (this.nodeType == 3);
    })
    .remove();
```

Found the code for removing the text afterward here https://stackoverflow.com/a/17852238/1415091

Answer (score 0):

Use `.html()`

```
var someText = 'Hey!';
$('#test').html('<p>' + someText + '</p>');
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/howderek/3t3Lw75x/