# Within HTML TD Tag: remove text, keep html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML:

```
<td aria-describedby="26c980b7-c0e9-416d-b904-5f7454ac67a5" role="gridcell">
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="onReeferPopup(event)" checked="checked" name="reefer">
    NOR
</td>
```

I have a js function in which I have the td-element. How do I remove the text 'NOR' and KEEP the checkbox?

```
tdElement.prop("innerHTML", "");
tdElement.prop("textContent", "");
tdElement.prop("outerText", "");
```

All remove the the text AND the checkbox

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17852238/519413) specifically in the duplicate I've marked.

Answer (score 0):

Since `NOR` isn't in its own element, use `replace` on the returned html value.

```js
var tdInput = $('td[role="gridcell"] input');
$('td[role="gridcell"]').html(tdInput);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead></thead>
  <tbody>
    <td aria-describedby="26c980b7-c0e9-416d-b904-5f7454ac67a5" role="gridcell">
      <input type="checkbox" onclick="onReeferPopup(event)" checked="checked" name="reefer">
      NOR
    </td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What about cases where `NOR` is dynamic text that's not known at runtime?

Comment: Edited the answer. @RoryMcCrossan