# jQuery if div contains this text, replace that part of the text but not variable value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to remove only text part but not variable.
In following image I am trying to translate this line via JQuery.
following is the code I am using:

Want to change only text not the part which is enclosed in strong tag.

```js
$('.content-box__row div:nth-child(3)').text('');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div role="cell" class="review-block__content" data-review-section="shipping-cost">
        Passport Priority Duties and Taxes Paid
        ·
        <strong class="emphasis">
          <span class="skeleton-while-loading--inline">14,96&nbsp;€</span>
        </strong>

    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Try look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/17852238/2943218

Comment: You can wrap what you need deleted in a separate `span` and target the new `span` instead

Comment: @otejiri I can't edit this page. Shopify doesn't let us.

Comment: you can edit the span: `$('.skeleton-while-loading--inline').text('some text');`

Comment: @zb22, want to replace "Passport Priority Duties and Taxes Paid" this part of the code

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I think following code will work , will you please help me to apply this in my current code.
function removeText(element){
  var newElement = $('<' + element[0].nodeName + '/>');
  for(i=0; i < item.attributes.length; i++) {
    newElement.attr(item.attributes[i].name, item.attributes[i].value);
  } 
  element.children().each(function(){
    newElement.append(this);
  });
  element.replaceWith(newElement);
}

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I want to replace it with "Droits et taxes de passeport prioritaires payés"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$('.content-box__row div:nth-child(3)').contents().filter(function() {
  return (this.nodeType == 3);
}).first().replaceWith("Droits et taxes de passeport prioritaires payés");
```

This will only replace the first part, aka what you want..

```js
$('.content-box__row div:nth-child(3)').contents().filter(function() {
  return (this.nodeType == 3);
}).first().replaceWith("Droits et taxes de passeport prioritaires payés");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content-box__row">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div role="cell" class="review-block__content" data-review-section="shipping-cost">
    Passport Priority Duties and Taxes Paid ·
    <strong class="emphasis">
          <span class="skeleton-while-loading--inline">14,96&nbsp;€</span>
        </strong>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :)
but this code partially working following is the snapshot of output 
[link](https://ibb.co/VttSnHg)

Comment: It worked it was my fault didn't catch the correct selector :) 
Thanks a lot Carsten  :)