# How do I delete text within an element without deleting children?

Tags: jquery

How do i can remove the "John Doo" text in this block and then add some html content?

```
<label><input type="radio" name="field-value-1359303" value="Joe Doe">Joe Doe</label>
```

My "solution"

```
$('input[value="Joe Doe"]')
  .hide()
  .parents('label')
  ????
  .append('<div>my content</div>');
```

The end result should be as follows:

```
<label><input type="radio" name="field-value-1359303" value="Joe Doe"><div>my content</div></label>
```

Comment: Use the .text() function for that : https://api.jquery.com/text/

Comment: try look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715167/jquery-how-to-remove-the-text-but-not-the-children-elements

Comment: Did you want to remove the entire `radio` button?  Or just change the text for the radio?   Seems you don't need the `label` if there's no `radio` (so you would replace the label's parent)

Comment: I want to hide the radio button and the text next to it. And add my content inside the label where the hidden radio button is located. Update description in question

Comment: @Lk77 but $('label').text() delete all content inside. And i want to save input element, but delete text after input

Comment: @AlexandrTimoshchuk then better to put the text in a span

Answer (score 1):

You could use vanilla javascript (not jQuery)

NOTE: for this code to run as is you have to add id="lab" to the label element.

1st solution (innerHTML is not the best decision)

```
let label = document.getElementById('lab');
const kid  = label.children[0];
let new_message = "Jane Doe";
label.innerHTML = "";
label.appendChild(kid);
label.innerHTML = label.innerHTML + new_message;
```

With this solution I assume you can have access to the label element.

2nd solution (you have to change the structure of your html)

```
let label = document.getElementById('lab');
const kid  = label.children[0];
let span = document.createElement('span');
let new_message = "Jane Doe";
span.textContent = new_message;
while (label.firstChild) {
    label.removeChild(label.firstChild);
}
label.appendChild(kid);
label.appendChild(span);
```

Personally I would go with the second solution because innerHTML can lead to problems and I don't think an additional span would create any issues.

Comment: Thank you! But there's a small problem - I have a lot of elements and I don't know what content will be inside them. So I can't hardcode "jane doe" because every day there will be new content in that label.

Comment: You can use variables, for text and other elements too. Can you be more specific on what types your content can be on? Anyhow I believe you can use this code as a base. e.g. you can add instead of a span a div with other elements inside it

Comment: FYI you *can* use jquery, using `.contents()` and filter on `this.nodeType == 3` - see provided existing answer(s).

Answer (score 1):

You must declare a param to save the input, clear label body by html() before appending the input and div

```js
const input = $("input[value='Joe Doe']");
$('label').html("").append(input).append('<div>my content</div>');
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.slim.js"></script>
<label><input type="radio" name="field-value-1359303" value="Joe Doe">Joe Doe</label>
```